# Joins in cakephp using find

Tags: php, cakephp, join, find

I have used join query which joins three tables employee, places and employee_places.The join query gives me all the results as I have used find('all').But in the view page I just want to show employee name from employee table - place name from place table in a dropdown.
e.g:- emp1-place1,emp2-place2 and so on. Where should I give the fields name in find.
Look at the following code :

$options['joins'] = array(
            array('table' => 'employees',
                'alias' => 'emp',
                'type' => 'inner',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'emp.id = EmployeePlace.employee_id '
                )
            ),
            array('table' => 'places',
                'alias' => 'pl',
                'type' => 'inner',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'pl.id = EmployeePlace.place_id'
                )
            )
        );

$empTables = $this->Bill->EmployeePlace->find('all', $options);

$this->set(compact('empTables'));

The above query results the following array:-

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [EmployeePlace] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [employee_id] => 1
                    [place_id] => 1
                    [Date] => 2011-02-02
                )

```
        [Employee] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [image] => 
                [firstName] => Andy
                [lastName] => Murray
                [date_of_joining] => 2010-09-02
                [date_of_leaving] => 2011-02-02
                [date_of_birth] => 1991-08-10
                [gender] => Male
                [supervisor] => 0
                [designation] => Manager
                [user_id] => 0
            )

        [Place] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [placeName] => table-1
                [section_id] => 1
                [position] => Left
                [seating_capacity] => 4
            )


    )
```

)

I just want firstName from employee - placeName from place table in the dropdown. How do I do this using condition in find.

Comment: There are virtual fields in Model which could help.

Comment: If  you give a example on the above code that would be better.

Comment: Virtual fields can only combine fields in one model, if I recall correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use containable: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable

You will then only be dealing with data that you require.

Loop over the results and build the strings you want. Add the strings to an array indexed against the value you want the selection to return. Pass the array out to the view.

How are you going to handle the values? What do you want to do when a user has made a selection?

OR:

You could create a [db view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/views.html), which is a table that combines data from other tables on the fly. CakePHP can access this as a normal table.

Comment: - Containable works fine for me. Infact it also gives the same results what Iam getting by using joins. Now I struck how to pass these arrays to the view because I only want employee.firstName - place.placeName in my dropdown. So how to pass the values to view. I have the whole array.

Comment: - I have solved the issue now .Everything is working fine now. Thnx a lot for your help.